# how to increment price if number of days increase in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, increment

**view.py**

```
def booking(request):
    
    all_location = location.get_all_location()
    all_products = Product.get_all_products()
    data = {'amount': 5000}
    data['product'] = all_products
    data['location'] = all_location
    
    return render(request, 'booking.html', data)
```

**my html file**

```
   <input type='number' placeholder='enter days' </div>
    <div class="mb-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control p-4" placeholder="" required="required"> **{% comment %}Want to Get Value from days and save it variable {% endcomment %}**
        </div>
      </div> ** <p>Amount = RS {{amount}} </p> **{% comment %}Want to Save amount in variable if user increase days then amount variable get increment {% endcomment %}** ** <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control py-3 px-4" rows="3" placeholder="Special Request" required="required"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

- I want to get and amount days value in variable then want to increment the amount if user increase days. I get the amount dynamically by view function and my other problem is that how to prevent user to change amount from source code.  *

Comment: DO you mean you want to do this directly in the web page? You will need JS for that (or alternatively something like `htmx`). Once the template is rendered, pure django cannot change the contents.

Comment: -michijnch ! first thank you for replay. no matter if this done by Django or JS or any other way I'll be grateful to you If you guide me. thanks for giving me your precious time.

Comment: You need to learn to manipulate the DOM. JS is the standard way of doing this - https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/javascript-dom-manipulation/